# Use TikZ decoration in a scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Rather than define a single decorator for all lines at the `tikzpicture` level, I'd like to use scopes to selectively apply certain decorations to certain parts of my drawing. As a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%%% Draw the axis.
\begin{scope}[decoration={ticks}]
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [decorate] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This should produce an axis eight units long with tick marks, and the decoration should not "bleed" into other areas of the figure.

Instead, I get an axis, but no tickmarks!

**EDIT:** It turns out, calling `\usetikzlibrary{decorations}` in the preamble doesn't work. Instead, use `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}`. Can anyone tell me why loading the whole decorations library doesn't work?

Comment: Please post a complete and compilable, but minimal example. This means with all required packages and TikZ libraries but with no unrelated thing like `scale` (there is a `]` missing anyway). Thanks.

Comment: You mean using a full preamble with minimal document class?

Comment: Yes a full preamble. If now with `article` or `minimal` class doesn't matter. The *minimal* refers to *no unrelated code*, not to the `minimal` class. Also you should put an @Martin in your comment so that I get notified about your comment. This isn't required for the original author of the question or answer, which is the reason I skipped the @jrhorn424 in my comments.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the tips! As you can tell, I'm a bit new. I'll update the example I include for completeness, but I think I may have found a solution to my original question.

Comment: The minimal example doesn't compile for me (even with `decorations.pathmorphing`), it complains about not knowing the `axis` key. Is this a style you defined yourself somewhere else? Also, if you manage to find a solution to your problem, you can post that as an answer and accept it, to close the issue.

Comment: In answer to your question about why doesn't `\usetikzlibrary{decorations}` result in the `decorations.pathmorphing` library also be loaded, it's better to think of `decorations` as a base library and `decorations.pathmorphing` as an extension, rather than `decorations.pathmorphing` as a sub-library of `decorations`.  The dot doesn't have any special LaTeX meaning here; it's just the file that contains the code is called `tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex`.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for that explanation. It seems then that `\usetikzlibrary{decorations}` would be looking for `tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex`, which looks like it might just load code common to all the "extensions".

Comment: @Jake, I just fixed the typos. Thanks for that. Also, I didn't know whether I should answer my own question. I felt pretty sheepish about not figuring it out before posting! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires the library `decorations.pathreplacing`. The `axis` style for a path doesn't exist by default. Perhaps you can clarify that. The code below works. But perhaps not as expected.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[decoration={ticks}]
      \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
      \draw[decorate] (0,0) -- (8,0);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```